# K-theory of complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^n$. I am searching for literature on the K-theory for $X$? I guess the K-theory is known...

Comment: Do you mean topological $K$-theory, or the algebraic one? The first one is known. The algebraic one is essentially equivalent to the Chow ring, which is far from being understood.

Comment: I mean the algebraic one. So what is known for $K_0(X)$?

Comment: Essentially nothing. Please ask a precise question.

Comment: For example under what kind of assumptions on $X$ $K_0(X)$ is finitely generated ? Maybe for complete intersections of genus zero...

Comment: What is genus 0?? This happens for degree 1 and 2 and for  cubic surfaces. That's all.

Comment: No, I mean $p_a=\mathrm{dim}H^d(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$, where $d=\mathrm{dim}(X)$. By Serre duality this cohomology is $H^0(X,\omega_X)$ and $\omega_X=\mathcal{O}_X(\sum d_i-n-1)$. With the surjection $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(n))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(n))$ for all $n$ there are some complete intersections with $p_a=0$.

Comment: @abx: Since you seem to be an expert, why not provide an answer or some references?

Comment: @Aleksa, **please** edit your question so that it contains your complete question. Comments should not be part of the question!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by  Daniel Loughran, I will try to  answer the question whether $K_0(X)$ is finitely generated. First, the Chern character from $K_0(X)$ to the Chow ring $CH(X)$ is an isomorphism modulo torsion: see for instance Fulton, *Intersection Theory*, Cor. 18.3.2. Thus we can transfer the question to $CH(X)$, and use [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76314/genus-of-smooth-varieties-with-small-chow-group/125046#125046)). So, at least conjecturally, for a complete intersection $X$ the  group $K_0(X)$ is finitely generated iff $h^{p,q}(X)=0$ for $p\neq q$. This holds if and only if $X$ is a quadric, a cubic surface, or  an even-dimensional intersection of 2 quadrics (see M. Rapoport, *Complément à l'article de P. Deligne "La
conjecture de Weil pour les surfaces K3"*, Inv. math. 15 (1972), 227-236).